# Finding the maximum value of $n$

Tags: number-theory

What's the maximum value for $n$ for which there is a set of distinct positive integers $k_{1}, k_{2}, ... , k_{n}$ for which $k_{1}^{2} + k_{2}^{2} + ... + k_{n}^{2} = 2002$

Comment: What have you tried so far?  A big part of this problem is finding some $n$ that satisfies the equation.  Then try to find a smaller $n$, and when you can't get any smaller you prove that no smaller $n$ is possible.  So at least you can do step 1!

Comment: Means this is a question of Trial & Error ?? .. I was just brainstorming to find an algebraic way but couldn't figure it out ..

Comment: Note that $1^2+2^2+\dots+18^2>2002$, so $n\le17$.

Comment: @Erick Technically, he did write *maximum* value of $n$, not minimum.  It is then "try to find a *bigger* $n$."  Although I don't know what value of $n$ will suffice, or even if it is possible, I can tell you that if it exists it will be less than $2002$.  Or as almagest points out, $17$ also works as an upper bound from the above argument.

Comment: And $1^2+\dots+12^2+14^2+16^2+18^2+24^2=2002$, so $n\ge16$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2+6^2+7^2+8^2+9^2+10^2+11^2+12^2+14^2+16^2+18^2+24^2=2002$ which uses 16 distinct squares.

$1^2+\dots+18^2=2109>2002$, so any 18 distinct squares have too large a sum. So the only question is whether it can be done with 17.

Note that $1^2+2^2+\dots+17^2=1785=2002-217$ and $18^2-10^2=224>217$, so we must include $1^2+2^2+\dots+10^2=385$ if we have 17 squares.

If we start from $1^2+\dots+17^2=1785$, and add a square larger than $18^2$ we are adding at least $19^2=361$, so we must drop at least $12^2$. That works!

$1^2+\dots+11^2+13^2+14^2+15^2+16^2+17^2+19^2=2002$ with 17 squares.